# 2-D Fourier series components from image

Tags: image-processing, fourier-analysis

Suppose I draw a black/white image where the color black represents 1.0 and the color white represents 0. Is there a way to extract numerical estimates for the coefficients of a (real) 2-D Fourier series which approximates this image?

Here is a simple example:
[image]

What about for more complex images such as:

[image]

or

[image]

Comment: To clarify, do you want to take the DFT of these images? Or get a symbolic function to work with?

Answer (score 1):

As you want a real FFT, the picture must by symmetric or anti-symmetric.
Here is a simple symmetric example:

```
dat = Table[If[x^2 + y^2 < 4, 0, 1], {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}];
MatrixPlot[dat]
fdat = FourierDCT[dat] // Chop;
MatrixPlot[fdat]
```

Here a more complicated one:

```
n = 5;
dat = Table[If[OddQ[x + y], 0, 1], {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}];
MatrixPlot[dat]
fdat = FourierDCT[dat] // Chop;
MatrixPlot[fdat]
```

And here a circle:

```
n = 100;
dat = Table[If[x^2 + y^2 < .5 10^4, 0, 1], {x, -n, n}, {y, -n, n}];
MatrixPlot[dat]
fdat = FourierDCT[dat] // Chop;
MatrixPlot[fdat]
```